# VBA to Create a Folder and Save as a pdf within the folder

Tags: vba, pdf, directory, save

i'm very new to VBA and have an issue.

I've received help in saving a file into a specific folder but not allowing me to overwrite the file.

```
Sub Autosave2()
Dim vDir
Dim strFileExists, pdfname, fileSaveName As String
Dim FSO

pdfname = ActiveSheet.Range("Q2")
vDir = "\\Reports\Internal PO Log\PO pdf's\"
If Right(pdfname, 3) = "pdf" Then
    fileSaveName = vDir & pdfname
Else
    fileSaveName = vDir & pdfname & ".pdf"
End If
MsgBox fileSaveName
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not FSO.FileExists(fileSaveName) Then
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fileSaveName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        MsgBox "PDF File Saved (CentreSoft\Reports\Internal PO Log\PO pdf's)"
    Else
        MsgBox "THIS PO NUMBER ALREADY EXISTS"
    End If

End Sub
```

I now need to create a folder with the same name (Range("Q2")) and save the file as a pdf within the new folder (with the same name; PO number in this scenario)

I also need to display messages should the folder already exits thus blocking the code from running any further.

Any help would be hugely appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Sub Autosave2()

Dim vDir
Dim strFileExists, pdfname, fileSaveName As String
Dim separator As String: separator = Application.PathSeparator
Dim FSO

pdfname = ActiveSheet.Range("Q2")
vDir = "\\Reports\Internal PO Log\" & pdfname

If Dir(vDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
   'create folder
    MkDir vDir
Else
   MsgBox "The folder already exits thus blocking the code from running any further."
   Exit Sub
End If

If Right(pdfname, 3) = "pdf" Then
    fileSaveName = vDir & separator & pdfname
Else
    fileSaveName = vDir & separator & pdfname & ".pdf"
End If

'MsgBox fileSaveName

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not FSO.FileExists(fileSaveName) Then
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=fileSaveName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        MsgBox "PDF File Saved in " & vDir
    Else
        MsgBox "THIS PO NUMBER ALREADY EXISTS"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: There was a problem in the code. I updated it. A separator was missing to create the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it :-)

```
Sub Autosave2()

Dim vDir
Dim strFileExists, pdfname, fileSaveName As String
Dim FSO
Dim FldrName As String

pdfname = ActiveSheet.Range("Q2")
FldrName = "\\Reports\Internal PO Log\PO pdf's\" & pdfname & "\" & pdfname
vDir = "\\Reports\Internal PO Log\PO pdf's\" & pdfname

If Dir(vDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        'continue
Else
        MsgBox "The folder already exits thus blocking the code from running any further."
        Exit Sub
End If

'create folder
MkDir vDir

If Right(pdfname, 3) = "pdf" Then
    fileSaveName = FldrName & ".pdf"
Else
    fileSaveName = FldrName & ".pdf"
End If

'MsgBox fileSaveName

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not FSO.FileExists(fileSaveName) Then
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fileSaveName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        MsgBox "PDF File Saved in " & vDir
    Else
        MsgBox "THIS PO NUMBER ALREADY EXISTS"
    End If

End Sub
```

Not too sure if it's the best work around but i've created a new FldrName and pointed everything towards that in the file save

Thanks so much for getting me that far.....you've been a great help